# classcast exception in change font

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I wanted to change font for a text field from Window->prefernce->change font option. I implemented the code.
But what happens is while updating the text field I am getting following classcast exception. Following is the code for adding the font dialog in Preference

```
public class SampleViewPreferencePage extends FieldEditorPreferencePage implements
        IWorkbenchPreferencePage {

    public SampleViewPreferencePage() {
        super(GRID);

    }

    public void createFieldEditors() {

        addField(new FontFieldEditor("font", "Font selection",
                getFieldEditorParent()));
    }

    @Override
    public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
        setPreferenceStore(SvtActivator.getDefault().getPreferenceStore());

    }

}
```

SampleView-> createPartControl()

```
/**
     * This is a callback that will allow us to create the viewer and initialize
     * it.
     */
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

        super.createPartControl(parent);
        FillLayout layout = new FillLayout();
        layout.marginHeight = layout.marginWidth = 10;
        parent.setLayout(layout);
        text = new StyledText(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText("");




    }

@Override
    public void propertyChange(org.eclipse.jface.util.PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Value changed..");

        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
        System.out.println("newValue: "+newValue);
        //if (newValue instanceof FontData) {
            Font font = new Font(Display.getCurrent(),
                    (FontData) newValue);
            getText().setFont(font);
        //}

    }





java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData; cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData
    at com.example.MyView.propertyChange(MyView.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore$3.run(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.firePropertyChangeEvent(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter.setValue(PreferenceConverter.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FontFieldEditor.doStore(FontFieldEditor.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditor.store(FieldEditor.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage.performOk(FieldEditorPreferencePage.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.performApply(PreferencePage.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage$2.widgetSelected(PreferencePage.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ShowPreferencePageHandler.execute(ShowPreferencePageHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at de.allianz.abs.konvertortool.product.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Can you add the method: `com.example.MyView.propertyChange`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the `[L` at the beginning of  the first part of the class cast exception `[Lorg.eclipse.swt.graphics.FontData`. This means the value is an array of `FontData` so you need to do:

```
Font font = new Font(Display.getCurrent(),
        (FontData []) newValue);
```

You should also make sure you call `dispose` on any fonts you create.

Answer (score 0):

During runtime, the class loaded is not the same as the class the calling code was compiled against.  Make sure your runtime libraries are the same as your build libraries and that you do not have multiple versions of API's in either your runtime or build.

Comment: I have not added any extra libraries. I created a simple eclipse rcp application with view. And added the a text. and added preference.Is there any possibility to be changed the runtime libraries? I am sure I have not added any extra library.